# i want to change the width of the video player when it comes to tablet size

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to change the width of the video player when it comes to tablet size.
I tried like below but it didn't work. help please!

the below code is for video component:

***Video.js***

```
 import React from 'react'
    import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
    import './Video.css'
    
    function Video() {
        return (
        
    <ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFREKvAKP_0' autoPlay muted />
        )
    }
    
    export default Video
```

---

```
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width:1023px)
{
max-width: 50%;
}
```

the above code is the CSS for the video component that needs to be smaller when the screen enters the tablet size.

Comment: Where is the css selector? browser will not know to which element you want max-width to be applied. Have a look at https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ you'll get your mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFREKvAKP_0' autoPlay muted className="react__player" />


@media ( min-width: 769px ) and ( max-width: 1023px ) {
  .react__player{
     max-width: 50%;
     max-height: 250px; 
     margin-right: 20px;
     
  }
}
```